# A cycle was detected in the build path of project in maven

Tags: java, maven

There are many headlines on this error. But I can't find solution for me.

I am going to create a multi-module project. `parentProject`, `projectA`, `projectD`, `projectUtil` and `projectW`. `projectW`'s packaging is **war** and contain `projectA`, `projectD` and `projectUtil` **jar** file.

```
projectParent
├───projectA
│   ├───src
│   │   └───main/java/projectA
│   │       ├───ClassA.java
│   │       └───ClassB.java
│   └───pom.xml ---- packaging = jar & dependencies = projectD and projectUtil
├───projectD
│   ├───src
│   │   └───main/java/projectD
│   │       ├───ClassC.java
│   │       └───ClassD.java
│   └───pom.xml ---- packaging = jar & dependencies = projectA and projectUtil
├───projectUtil
│   ├───src
│   │   └───main/java/projectUtil
│   │       └───StringUtil.java
│   └───pom.xml ---- packaging = jar & dependencies = no dependency
├───projectW
│   ├───src
│   │   └───main/java/projectW
│   │       └───Test.java
│   └───pom.xml ---- packaging = war & dependencies = projectA, projectD and projectUtil
└───pom.xml ---- packaging = pom & modules = projectA, project D, projectUtil and projectW
```

There was error like *a cycle was detected in the build path of project.* And I turned to the errors into warnings like solution on internet.

> Windows -> Preferences -> Java-> Compiler -> Building -> Circular
>   Dependencies

Test.java is worked successfully but maven not install due to this warning now. Could anybody suggest me an solution with the following exception?

[image]

Test.java

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
a.getD().mrbDunya();

ClassD d = new ClassD();
d.getB().sayHello();
```

**EDIT**

parentProject/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.earslan</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectParent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Project Parent</name>

    <modules>
        <module>projectA</module>
        <module>projectD</module>
        <module>projectUtil</module>
        <module>projectW</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

projectA/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.earslan</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectParent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Project A</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.earslan</groupId>
            <artifactId>projectD</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.earslan</groupId>
            <artifactId>projectUtil</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

projectUtil/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.earslan</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectParent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>projectUtil</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Project Util</name>

    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

projectW/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.earslan</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectParent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>projectW</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Project W</name>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Project Files Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.earslan</groupId>
            <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.earslan</groupId>
            <artifactId>projectD</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.earslan</groupId>
            <artifactId>projectUtil</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSF Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PrimeFaces Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Add the pom files

Comment: @Jens pom files of projectW or all of them?

Comment: You somehow need to remove the cyclic dependency. If this cannot be done by moving classes around, it may help to define interfaces and depend on them rather than the implementation class.

Comment: @EmreArslan all of them

Answer (score 1):

> ├──projectA
>   │   ├───src
>   │   │   └───main/java/projectA
>   │   │       ├───ClassA.java
>   │   │       └───ClassB.java
>   │   └───pom.xml ---- packaging = jar & dependencies = projectD and projectUtil
>   ├───projectD
>   │   ├───src
>   │   │   └───main/java/projectD
>   │   │       ├───ClassC.java
>   │   │       └───ClassD.java
>   │   └───pom.xml ---- packaging = jar & dependencies = projectA and projectUtil

Project A is dependent upon Project D which is dependent upon Project A, which is clearly circular.

You need to refactor by either

1. moving classes between projects;
2. just merge the two together;
3. introduce a 3rd project (which A and D would both depend upon) containing just the mutually dependent classes.